# How to get the data on the same row if the data is on two rows on excel or power query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

[image]

I wish to get the paid row on the same row as the issued

please help either on Excel or Power BI

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or have errors. Reading [ask] and [repro] should help you to improve your question.

Comment: Provide more sample data. Are there more rows for XYZ or always only two rows. Is there sometimes NOT matching Paid row for a Issued row?  What have you tried to accomplish this.

Comment: I just can't understand your question, what would you like to achieve and what have your tried will help in understanding

Comment: Fill down on the Acct column, then Pivot on the Status with no aggregation